# Node structure gains itself as a parent during expansion

Tags: c, pointers

My assignment is to write a solver for 3x3 sliding tile puzzle which has to embedded later.

I have the structure

```
struct node
{
 char state[9];
 struct node* parentNode;
 char lastMove;
} node;
```

I use a pseudo stack for

```
struct node
{
 char state[9];
 struct node* parentNode;
 char lastMove;
} node;
```

I use a stack which will be used later for the IDS algorithm.

```
struct node stack[60000];
struct node* Node = stack;
#define push(Node, n) (*((Node)++) = (n))
#define pop(Node) (*--(Node))
```

My function expandNode creates all valid child nodes of its given parent

```
void expandNode(struct node* parent)
{
char help;
int emptyField = -1;
struct node newNode;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    if (parent->state[i] == '0') emptyField = i;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if(lastMoveVal(parent->lastMove, moves[i]) == '0') continue;
    if (moveValid(parent->state, moves[i]) == '1')
    {
        newNode.parentNode = parent;
     ...
```

My main function

```
void main()
{
 struct node root;
 char rootState[9] = { '6','8','3','0','4','5','1','7','2' };
 assignArray(root.state, rootState);
 push(Node, root);
 struct node curr;
 curr  = pop(Node);
 expandNode(&curr);
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
    curr = pop(Node);
    printf("\n");
    for(int j = 0; j<9; j++)
    {
        printf("%c", curr.state[j]);
    };
    printf("  PARENT: ");
    for(int j = 0; j<9; j++)
    {
        printf("%c", curr.parentNode->state[j]);
    };
  }
 }
```

Here is the output:
683405172  PARENT: 683405172
683145072  PARENT: 683145072
083645172  PARENT: 083645172

As you see the expansion of the nodes is correct but the state of the parent node is not the expected 683045172 but the state of node itself.

Comment: The lack of dynamic allocation (`malloc`)  in your `expandNode` function is very suspicious. I have a hunch that you are storing pointers to object that go out of scope in the function (but hard to say with only this snippet)

Comment: I can't work dynamically because the board that will be used later doesn't have a heap and I'm forced to work with static arrays.

Comment: The `...` in `expandNode` hides a lot of logic. It doesn't show how child nodes are pushed to the stack.

Comment: if (moves[i] == 'U')  
              {
                  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)  
                  {
                      newNode.state[i] = parent->state[i];  
                  }
                    newNode.lastMove = 'U';  
                    char help = newNode.state[emptyField - 3];
                    newNode.state[emptyField - 3] = newNode.state[emptyField];
                    newNode.state[emptyField] = help;
                    printf("U");
                    push(Node, newNode);
                    continue;

4x the same if but with different swap for each mov